# Defining properties in header file vs implementation file objective c

Tags: objective-c

In the page based application template, I am seeing this a lot in the implementation (.m) files.

```
@interface ModelController()
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageData;
@end
```

Why isn't this done in the header (.h) file?

Answer (score 13):

This property is in the implementation file because it does not need to be declared publicly and only used within the .m file.